# A faster way of setting width and height than setLayoutParams?

Tags: android, layoutparams

I'm trying to write a code that resizes a view's width and height by animating it, and to do that, what I've done is getting `LayoutParams` of the view once, and every 16 ms get a width and a height value from an `int[]` and change the width and height of the `LayoutParams` using them, and finally do `view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);` to change the view's size.

This works fine, but it takes a little too much to `.setLayoutParams()`, and so when I give it a duration value of 1000 ms, it takes around 1500 ms to finish animating.

You can see my code fully [here](https://gist.github.com/SIMMORSAL/d73695c4a785b82923a0b46ef7fba584).
(P.S the code is not finished yet and I'm aware of it's problems)

Is there an alternative way to set width and height to a view that is faster? I thought about setting margin, but that has limitations for what I'm trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @saltandpepper unfortunately no. But i tested it on some widgets (not thoroughly) and found out that it's OK to use on `TextViews` (gives a 30 - 40 fps on 1440p screens and 40 - 50 on 1080p) but not on `ImageViews` (on 1440p gives you a 10 - 20 fps first time you run it, and each time after that fps gets reduced. I was around 1 - 2 fps the 10th iteration). Using it on a say `LinearLayout` with some widgets in it, all with fixed sizes will be pretty smooth.

Comment: I've found that using View.setScaleX and View.setScaleY work well as well (for me it is in the context of a CoordinatorLayout and a custom CoordinatorLayout.Behaviour, that scales and moves an ImageView based on the scrollstate).